# Position text over textarea

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a div/text to the top right corner of my textarea.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="textarea-container">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <div id="copy">copy</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
div#textarea-container {
    position: absolute;
}

div#copy {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
```

What adjustments need to be made?

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zrpgK/

Comment: Do you want the text inside of the textarea? Or just outside of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Working jsfiddle code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrpgK/11/)

```
div#textarea-container {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
}
div#copy {
   position: absolute;
   right: 5px;
   top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrpgK/12/)

You need to give your text area a width. That way, you can know that where you place your positioned div is within the bounds of your text area.

```
div#textarea-container { position: relative; }
div textarea { width: 100%; }
div#copy {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div#textarea-container {
    position: absolute;
}
div#copy {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:-40px;
    margin-right:5px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Puts it right at the right corner.
Heres the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zrpgK/13/